# Area 51: where and how to pitch intended topic and scope?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I've put up a proposal for a [Plots](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32907/plots?referrer=1kqo7yHkIsmrXeyAZbdy3g2) Stack Exchange on Area51. My idea for this site is that it would be for questions clarifying the plot of narrative works (encompassing all media, from science-fiction television series to John Grisham novels).

I have examples of the kind of questions that are good and in-scope may *seem* objective but are really subjective, as well as questions that, while objective, are outside the scope of a plot (such as "Why was Neville Longbottom in Gryffindor?"). If I can't vote for my own examples, how should I communicate which is which?

Comment: Add comments? However, it should be obvious from the way the proposal is worded.

Comment: @ChrisF: Where do we "word" a proposal? The target audience field?

Comment: Yes. It's been a while since I was active on Area 51 so I'm not sure what (if anything) has changed in that regard.

Comment: I've closed this proposal as overlapping with [Literature](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature). Plot-related questions (at least those that aren't too subjective or that ask for someone else to do their homework) should fit in completely.

Answer (score 2):

Proposals in Area 51 are not supposed to be owned by any one person.  So you can suggest a topic, and describe the audience, but it's up to everyone who follows the proposal to define exactly what is on-topic and off-topic.

The way on-topic and off-topic are defined is by suggesting questions, and then having users vote them on- or off-topic.  It's [generally frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92625/should-intended-as-x-comments-on-questions-be-permitted-on-area-51) to add a comment indicating what you intended a question to be.